# Setting Vollery ImgController with global variables extending application

Tags: java, android, image, global-variables, android-volley

Im trying to use volley to load an image from a url with the next line:

```
Image.setImageUrl(url, ImgController.getInstance().getImageLoader());
```

But ImgController could not be resolved. I checked and found out that I need to register my Custom Application context in AndroidManifest.xml file, with the following line:

```
<application android:name="ImgController" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

But i am already using a different context from my global variables (class that extends Application), like this:

```
<application android:name_"example.example.name.Global" android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

So here is my question, how can I set the ImgController without tampering with my Global varible class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using Volley ImageRequest, which works just fine.
Here is the code:

```
public void fetchBackgroundImage(String url){
    ImageRequest imgRequest = new ImageRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    Drawable banner = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                    findViewById(R.id.headerImage).setBackgroundDrawable(banner);
                }
            },256,88,null,
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {
                     System.out.println(ex.getMessage().toString());
                }
            }
    );
    RequestQueue rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    rq.add(imgRequest);
}
```